# pgAdmin III Why query results are shortened?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I've recently installed pgAdmin III 1.18.1 and noticed a strange thing:

Long json query results are shortened to 256 symbols and then ' (...)' is added.

Could someone help me disable this shortening?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Thanks to user [Erwin Brandstetter](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/3684/erwin-brandstetter) for his answer on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52399/why-are-query-results-shortened-in-pgadmin-1-18-1).

> There is a setting for that in the options: Max characters per column - useful when dealing with big columns. Obviously your setting is 256 characters.
>
> [image: pgadmin maxcharacter property]
>
> Set it higher or set it to -1 to disable the feature.

Comment: You can launch this options window on main window: file -> options

Comment: note for OS X you (for some reason) have to have the "server select" window focused before you can access the "preferences" menu [otherwise its grayed out]

Answer (score 0):

in pgadmin (Version 5.4) select

file >> preferences >> Query Tool >> Results grid

and change Resize by data? to false. This will the column be sized to the widest of the datatype or column name.