# Select whole column content in pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I use PosgreSQL as database and PgAdmin as tool to manage it. When I write simple select
(col is type of text and value of it is quite long, about 4k chars)

```
SELECT col FROM tab
```

I get this (there is about 250 chars before brackets):

```
abababababa(...)
```

but I inserted longer value. PgAdmin trim showed value and ends it with(...) string. How can I get whole content inside PgAdmin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgAdmin III 1.18 Why query results are shortened?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657852/pgadmin-iii-1-18-why-query-results-are-shortened)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try set this value in **PgAdmin config**:

```
File > Options > Query Tool > Max. characters per column
```

Look on settings [on this page](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/options-query_tool.html)

**EDIT:** For full column content you have to use `-1`, if left empty PgAdmin3 automatically replaces it with a 0 and nothing is shown but `"..."`.

Comment: Note that on Mac OS, the `File` menu will not show the `Options` item e.g. if the query window is focused. You have to focus the main application window to get the 'proper' `File` menu.

Comment: I found it under pgAdmin3 > Preferences > Query Tool > Query Editor > Max. characters per column

Comment: You should add to your answer that value needed to get full content must be -1 (if left empty, it's automatically replaced with a 0 and then you can't see anything)

Comment: Hi @EAmez, thanks for commend. Unfortunately, I haven't been using PgAdmin for over two years. If you are sure of the benefit of your note, please feel free to edit my answer ;)

Answer (score 19):

In PgAdmin.. If you want 'unlimited':
File -> Options -> Query Tool -> Max. char. per column -> -1