# Long strings are being clipped with (...) in postgres

Tags: postgresql

This relates to [How to concatenate strings of a string field in a PostgreSQL 'group by' query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870/how-to-concatenate-strings-of-a-string-field-in-a-postgresql-group-by-query)

```
SELECT table_name, string_agg(column_name, ', ') AS column_list
FROM   information_schema.columns 
where table_name not like 'pg_%'
GROUP  BY 1
order by table_name ;
```

I get column_list sometimes ending with:

```
"(...)"
```

Is that a feature of pgAdminIII?  How, can I get it to give me that data in its entirety?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgAdmin III Why query results are shortened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657852/pgadmin-iii-why-query-results-are-shortened) Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832460/select-whole-column-content-in-pgadmin?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you jpw: In PgAdmin's config, you can change how much is returned:

File > Options > Query Tool > Max. characters per column