# How to fetch [i.e. SELECT] full json text from Postgres Table with column having datatype as JSONB?

Tags: postgresql

I am unable to get entire json text from postgres table with column having datatype as JSONB.
Table Name: stud_profile_save
Column Name: sps_stud_dtls
Column DataType: JSONB

I tried below query in Postgres (PGAdmin)

```
SELECT sps_stud_dtls::jsonb from vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;
```

Got result as follows:

```
"{"email": "aditya010@test.com", "state": "MAHARASHTRA", "gender": "F", "address": "Thane", "pincode": "400605", "village": "KALWA S.O", "category": "1", "fullName": "Aditya Ten", "photoName": "433936_applicant_Photo.png", "tutionFees": "26000", "bankDetail (...)"
```

wherein actual text is as follows:

```
"{"email": "aditya010@test.com", "state": "MAHARASHTRA", "gender": "F", "address": "Thane", "pincode": "400605", "village": "KALWA S.O", "category": "1", "fullName": "Aditya Ten", "photoName": "433936_applicant_Photo.png", "tutionFees": "26000", "bankDetail (...)"

"{"email": "aditya010@test.com", "state": "MAHARASHTRA", "gender": "F", "address": "Thane", "pincode": "400605", "village": "KALWA S.O", "category": "1", "fullName": "Aditya Ten", "photoName": "433936_applicant_Photo.png", "tutionFees": "26000", "bankDetails": {"bankName": "IDBI BANK", "ifscCode": "IBKL0000221", "bankAccNo": "0221104000170260", "bankBranch": "ULHASNAGAR", "bankStmtFileName": "433936_bank_Passbook.png", "reEnterBankAccNo": "0221104000170260", "nameAsPerBankPassbook": "Aditya Ten"}, "blockTaluka": "THANE", "currentFees": "26500", "dateOfBirth": "06/06/2015", "familyIncome": 250000, "mobileNumber": "9999191919", "maritalStatus": "2", "nonTutionFees": "500", "parentDetails": {"title": "1", "lastName": "Lead", "firstName": "Testing", "middleName": "", "occupation": "7", "parentsMobileNo": "9999999999", "nameOfTheOrganization": "", "relationshipWithStudent": "F"}, "isProfileValid": 1, "currentTotalCgpa": "", "currentTotalMarks": "", "currAcadPercentage": "", "tutionFeeRecptName": "433936_expense_Of_Course.jpg", "currentCgpaObtained": "", "otherScholarshipAmt": "", "addressProofFileName": "433936_address_Proof.png", "currEducationDetails": {"institute": {"currAcadInstituteCode": 22984, "currAcadInstituteName": "BNBANDODKAR COLLEGE OF SCIENCE CHENDANI BUNDER ROAD THANE 400 601", "currAcadInstituteState": "MAHARASHTRA", "otherCurrInstituteFlag": "N"}, "currAcadCourseId": 5, "noOfYrsCompleted": 0, "currAcadCourseName": "B.Sc.-Bachelor of Science (BSc)", "currAcadCourseLevelId": 4, "lastAcadYearCompleted": "2021-2022", "currAcadCourseLevelName": "Under Graduate"}, "currentMarksObtained": "", "otherScholarshipName": "", "pastEducationDetails": [{"courseId": 384, "institute": {"state": "MAHARASHTRA", "instituteCode": -1, "instituteName": "AK Joshi", "otherPastEduInstituteFlag": "Y"}, "totalCgpa": "", "courseName": "Class 10", "percentage": 66.67, "totalMarks": "600", "cgpaObtained": "", "marksObtained": "400", "marksCGPACheck": "MARKS", "marksheetFileName": "433936_ssc_Marksheet.jpg", "monthAndYearOfPassing": "05-2014"}, {"courseId": 386, "institute": {"state": "MAHARASHTRA", "instituteCode": -1, "instituteName": "Test Institute", "otherPastEduInstituteFlag": "Y"}, "totalCgpa": "", "courseName": "Class 12", "percentage": 66.67, "totalMarks": "600", "cgpaObtained": "", "marksObtained": "400", "marksCGPACheck": "MARKS", "marksheetFileName": "433936_hsc_Marksheet.jpg", "monthAndYearOfPassing": "05-2016"}, {"courseId": 3, "institute": {"state": "", "instituteCode": null, "instituteName": "", "otherPastEduInstituteFlag": "N"}, "totalCgpa": "", "courseName": "Diploma", "percentage": "", "totalMarks": "", "cgpaObtained": "", "marksObtained": "", "marksCGPACheck": "MARKS", "marksheetFileName": "", "monthAndYearOfPassing": ""}, {"courseId": 4, "institute": {"state": "", "instituteCode": null, "instituteName": "", "otherPastEduInstituteFlag": "N"}, "totalCgpa": "", "courseName": "Graduation", "percentage": "", "totalMarks": "", "cgpaObtained": "", "marksObtained": "", "marksCGPACheck": "MARKS", "marksheetFileName": "", "monthAndYearOfPassing": ""}], "securedAdmissionFlag": "Y", "currentMarksCGPACheck": "MARKS", "identityProofFileName": "433936_id_Proof.jpg", "nonTutionFeeRecptName": "433936_TutitionNonTuitionReceipt.jpg", "admissionLetterFileName": "433936_Admission_Letter.png", "anyOtherScholarshipFlag": "N", "currAcadMarksheetFileName": "", "familyIncomeProofFileName": "433936_proof_Of_Income.jpg"}"
```

Could you help me to get/fetch this entire json text in postgres ?

Tried below query:

```sql
SELECT sps_stud_dtls::jsonb from vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;

SELECT JSON_EACH(sps_stud_dtls) FROM vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;

SELECT JSON_EACH_TEXT(sps_stud_dtls) FROM vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;

SELECT JSONB_EACH(sps_stud_dtls) FROM vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;

SELECT JSONB_EACH_TEXT(sps_stud_dtls) FROM vsp.stud_profile_save where sps_sr_id = 554723 ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgAdmin III Why query results are shortened?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19657852/pgadmin-iii-why-query-results-are-shortened)